# rpyc.Service takes 10 seconds to receive a 150kB object (on localhost, no LAN issue)

Tags: python, rpyc

I am building a big (150kB when pickled) dummy dictionary and running a dummy function on it that runs quickly and smoothly.

When the same function is exposed via a rpyc.Service, the time taken becomes 10 seconds (instead of 0.0009 seconds), even if my client and server stand on the same host (no issue with the LAN latency here).

Any idea why it takes so long for my 150kB object to be communicated from the client to the server on the same host?

And why the function `dummy.dummy()` is called even if the input object is not yet "available" (if it were, then the time spent in the function would be the same in the two test cases)?

Cf my python (3.2) code below. I measure the time spent in dummy.dummy(d).

1. Case 1: dummy.dummy is called by the client ; exec time = 0.0009
2. Case 2: dummy.dummy is called the rpyc service ; exec time = 10 seconds

**mini_service.py**

```
import rpyc
from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
import dummy

class miniService(rpyc.Service):
    def exposed_myfunc(self,d):
        #Test case 2: call dummy.dummy from the service
        dummy.dummy(d)

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = ThreadedServer(miniService,protocol_config = {"allow_public_attrs" : True}, port = 19865)
    t.start()
```

**mini_client.py**

```
import rpyc
import sys
import pickle
import dummy

def makedict(n):
    d={x:x for x in range(n)}
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d=makedict(20000)
    print(sys.getsizeof(d))             #result = 393356

#   output = open("C:\\rd\\non_mc_test_files\\mini.pkl",'wb') #117kB object for n=20k
#   pickle.dump(d,output)
#   output.close()

#RUN1 : dummy.dummy(d) out of rpyc takes 0.00099 seconds
#   dummy.dummy(d)

#RUN2 : dummy.dummy(d) via RPYC on localhost takes 9.346 seconds
    conn=rpyc.connect('localhost',19865,config={"allow_pickle":True})
    conn.root.myfunc(d)

    print('Done.')
```

**dummy.py**

```
import time

def dummy(d):
    start_ = time.time()
    for key in d:
        d[key]=0
    print('Time spent in dummy in seconds: ' + str(time.time()-start_))
```

Comment: Did you profile the time taken to access a single key(i.e. the time taken by `d[key] = 0`)? I believe rpyc does some serialization and send some message everytime you do `d[key] = 0` which obviously increases the time taken by thousandfolds[instead of a single python bytecode there is serialization + communication with the other process + obtaining the result, which is a lot of slow IO).

Comment: Good point. For the client, d[key]=0 iterated 10 times takes 0 seconds. For the service it takes an average of 0.002 seconds. Does it mean each modification of the object is synchronized with the client?

Comment: Yes. `0.002` for a single operation are way too much. It must be the IO between processes. If you want to make things faster you should avoid tiny operations on remote objects.

Comment: I am now performing a copy.deepcopy when I receive the object on the server side, and then work on the copy. This way, rpyc does not have to deal with keeping the reference synchonized between the client and the server. Problem solved. Note: it looks like allow_picke=True is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the performance loss comes from the work done by rpyc to keep the object (passed by reference) synchronized between the client and the server.

What I am now doing in my application is to make a **deep copy** of the input object, and then work on the copy, thus emulating a passing by value mechanism.

Note: the deep copying requires to have `allow_picke=True` set in the protocol configuration parameters.